# Boilerplate ant/maven config for apache-commons style packaging

Tags: java, ant, jar, apache-commons

The [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) family has a fairly standard packaging schema: 5 jars (classes, source, tests, tests-source and javadoc), an doc directory with HTML contents and a few text files (License, Readme):

```
.
├── docs
├── LICENSE.txt
├── NOTICE.txt
├── RELEASE-NOTES.txt
├── commons-io-2.4-javadoc.jar
├── commons-io-2.4-sources.jar
├── commons-io-2.4-test-sources.jar
├── commons-io-2.4-tests.jar
└── commons-io-2.4.jar
```

I'd like to package some of my projects in the same way, referencing the classes and methods to their corresponding javadocs so that eclipse can tool-tip the reference when using the imported class.

Is there a biolerplate configuration for either [Ant](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheAnt/article.html) or Maven for packaging in the Apache Commons style?

Comment: did you consider using maven for that? almost no boilerplate code at all ... no need to keep a local copy of your libraries as well. just specify what you're using and you're done...

Comment: Whichever works (updating my qestion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one part of this is easy - if you create your folder structure accordingly and do a release build in maven, all the jars will be created:

"${xxx}/src/main/java" will be used to create "${xxx}.jar" and "${xxx}-sources.jar"

"${xxx}/src/test/java" will be used to create "${xxx}-test.jar" and "${xxx}-test-sources.jar"

on top of that, the maven release plugin will ALSO create the javadocs and package them as "${xxx}-test-sources.jar"

all these will be uploaded to your maven repository - and you have to do nothing but put everything in the right place, then call the right maven goal.

on top of that, you could use the maven assembly plugin to do create a ZIP of all the artifacts created in your build. i don't have specific code for this, but you would have to get familiar with maven and the assembly plugin. i don't see a lot of complications there.

if you work with several people, you probably need some infrastructure - we have a general nexus for proxying the standard repositories locally, and then one repository per maven project.

when i did the transition to maven in our organisation, it was painful for a few days, because people had to get familiar with it. but it paid off - the projects are much smaller, and deploying release builds is a breeze.

i'd recommend getting into maven, then you will see how nice&friendly dependency management can be.